# How do I store many strings in one class like the example? (C#)

Tags: c#

I remember using something like this in school.
In a different class:

```
{
"string"
"string"
"string"
}
```

It was a class and I could go on to randomly pick one.

It's a basic question, but I struggled to find something online, because I didn't know how to word it correctly. I found different types of arrays, but they didn't really make anything more readable.

I tried storing it as an array, but in the long term it would just be too much. It's hard coded and would be hard to read if you try to remove single ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to store a collection of strings and randomly pick one, you can use a `List<string>` in C#.

Here's an example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a list of strings
        var strings = new List<string>()
        {
            "foo",
            "bar",
            "baz"
        };

        // Pick a random string
        var random = new Random();
        var index = random.Next(strings.Count);
        var randomString = strings[index];

        Console.WriteLine(randomString);
    }
}
```

This example creates a `List<string>` with three elements and then uses the `Random` class to pick a random index in the list.

Then it uses the index to retrieve the corresponding string from the list.

You can add or remove strings from the list as needed, and the code will still work.

Comment: Ah damn if i just searched for Lists i would've gotten it, thanks for the fast answer